# How to turn a string which should be split on the <space> an turned into an array of objects in mulesoft

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform

I am trying to turn a string which should be split  on the basis of space and turned into an array of objects.
Please help me how can I form it.

**Input**

```
field: YYC:16:26 YVR:16:03 YEG:13:43
```

**Output Expected**

```
"details" : [     
  {
    "field" : "YYC",         
    "time" : "16:26"     
   },  
   {
      "field" : "YVR",
      "Time" : "16:03"     
    }, 
    {
      "field" : "YEG",
      "Time" : "13:43"     
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight twist to what Karthik posted:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var test= "YYC:16:26 YVR:16:03 YEG:13:43" splitBy  " "
---
details: test map 
{
    "field": ($ splitBy ":")[0],
    "Time":  drop(($ splitBy ":"),1)joinBy ":"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to split first by sapce and then need to break the remaining string as below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var test= "YYC:16:26 YVR:16:03 YEG:13:43" splitBy  " "
---
details: test map ((item, index) -> 
{
    "field": item[0 to 2],
    "Time": item [4 to -1]
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way of approach similar to Anurag's solution

**DW**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var test= "YYC:16:26 YVR:16:03 YEG:13:43" splitBy  " "
---
details: test map ((item, index) -> 
{
    "field": (item splitBy ":")[0],
    "Time": (item splitBy ":")[1 to -1] joinBy ":"
})
```

Output

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "field": "YYC",
      "Time": "16:26"
    },
    {
      "field": "YVR",
      "Time": "16:03"
    },
    {
      "field": "YEG",
      "Time": "13:43"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. Resolves the issue :)
All the above code works amazingly